# Error "A docBase [...] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored" after WAR upload by Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, web-deployment, tomcat9

I am trying to deploy the WAR file from my Intellij to Tomcat that is on a remote host. I am using `Tomcat remote` Run/Debug Configuration. A Tomcat version is 9.0.39.

I am gettin the error:

> 01-Nov-2020 20:47:18.741 WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/home/u/.local/opt/tools/tomcat/teachers/teachers-0.0.1.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored

A bigger part of the error message is at the end of my question.
The WAR file is successfully uploaded to the remote host, extracted and DDL database insertions are automatically done as they should. But a site is not served.

Here there are files that I have configured in fresh Tomcat. Please help me how to fix the `` issue.

*./bin/setenv.sh*

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/u/.local/opt/tools/jdk
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
```

*./conf/tomcat-users.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
   <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
   <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
   <role rolename="manager-script"/>
   <user username="admin" password="pa$$word" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

*./conf/server.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="xxxlocalhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="teachers"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

*./conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="${catalina.base}/teachers/teachers-0.0.1.war">
</Context>
```

*./webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor"
                   sameSiteCookies="strict" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

*./webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor"
                   sameSiteCookies="strict" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

> u@hot:~/.local/opt/tools/tomcat$ cat logs/catalina.out

01-Nov-2020 21:44:19.308 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/home/u/.local/opt/tools/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml]
01-Nov-2020 21:44:19.309 WARNING [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/home/u/.local/opt/tools/tomcat/teachers/teachers-0.0.1.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
01-Nov-2020 21:44:19.312 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [/home/u/.local/opt/tools/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1830)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1620)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@3de116aa]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4966)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/home/u/.local/opt/tools/tomcat/teachers/ROOT] is not valid
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:751)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:708)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 29 more
01-Nov-2020 21:44:19.313 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/home/u/.local/opt/tools/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] has finished in [5] ms
01-Nov-2020 21:46:41.943 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(7363)-37.47.229.151] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [createStandardContext]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project? Is it possible to deploy artifact manually without IDE?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-root-application

```
├── bin
│   └── setenv.sh
├── conf
│   ├── Catalina
│   │   └── localhost
│   │       └── ROOT.xml
│   └── server.xml
├── deploy
│   └── gallery-0.0.1.war
└── wartest
    └── ROOT
```

*./conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="${catalina.base}/deploy/gallery-0.0.1.war">
</Context>
```

*./conf/server.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost" appBase="wartest" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

### Tomcat remote server

[image]

### WAR artifact

[image]

### SFTP Config

[image]

### Deployment paths

[image]

SSH for a local pc
[image]